# Simple Xml parse with Xdocument

Tags: c#, xml-parsing, linq-to-xml

I want parse xml in windows store app with Xdocument.

I tried this,but returned with null:

```
XDocument xDoc;
string title= "";

xDoc = XDocument.Load(url);

var elements = from x in xDoc.Descendants()
               select new
               {
                   title = x.Descendants("title").First().Value,
               };

foreach (var el in elements)
    _title = title;
```

Xml contents:

```
<title type='text'>tiitle</title>
<content type='text'> gfgdgdggd</content>
<link rel='related' type='application/atom+xml' href='http....'/>
```

How can is retrive text from attributes ?

Comment: Please clarify - do you want the value of the `title` element, or the value of the `type` attribute.

Comment: Your XML is invalid. You need to have a single root element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As ZevSpitz already mentioned, your XML is invalid. I modified it a bit to be able to test my code:

```
<root>
    <title type="text">title</title>
    <content type="text">gfgdgdggd</content>
</root>
```

You can retrieve values from the `type` attributes with the following code:

```
XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Parse(xml);

var types =
    from x in xDoc.Root.Descendants()
    select x.Attribute("type").Value;
```

In my case `xml` is declared as follows:

```
private string xml =
    @"<root>
        <title type=""text"">title</title>
        <content type=""text"">gfgdgdggd</content>
    </root>";
```

You can still use your code to load the XML from a URL if the file contents are the same.

Comment: Good call on using `Root`. I prefer not to use `.Value`, and instead cast to a `string`, because if there is no `type` attribute on the element the `Attribute` method will return `null` and calling the `Value` property will cause a `NullReferenceException`. If casting to `string`, the returned value will simply be null, which the `string` type can hold.

Comment: @ZevSpitz I guess it depends on the expected XML structure, but I like your approach. I'm sure it'll come in handy. I usually used `!= null` checking in such cases.

Comment: [How to: Retrieve the Value of an Element (LINQ to XML)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387049%28v=VS.100%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
var types =
    from e in xDoc.Descendants()
    select (string)e.Attribute("type");

foreach (string type in types) {
    Console.WriteLine(type);
}
```

Comment: Does it return `null` for all the elements? or only for one of them?